# Launching Terminal on Mac OS X from Adobe Air 2?

Tags: apache-flex, macos, actionscript, air, terminal

How do i launched Terminal from air 2 passing arguments and command as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this in [AIR 2](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/air2/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking if you can open the Terminal Application, I'm not sure how to do that yet.  But if you're asking how to execute scripts on the mac (which you normally do in the terminal/command-line), check out these tutorials/projects:

- [A Demonstration of the AIR 2 NativeProcess API](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2009/11/demo_of_nativeprocess_apis.html)
- [SearchCentral - Example AIR 2 App invoking NativeProcess](http://code.google.com/p/searchcentral/source/browse/trunk/src/SearchCentral.mxml)

Hope that helps,
Lance